# Compiling sample JNI code in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm having some major difficulty in compiling some sample C code (hello-jni.c) that came with android-ndk-r8b in Eclipse on Windows 7.  I followed the instructions from here http://mhandroid.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/using-eclipse-for-android-cc-development/
(In step 7, I changed `ndk-build` to `bash -c ndk-build` to get this to run correctly).  Eclipse spits out the following error:

```
12:23:44 **** Incremental Build of configuration Default for project MyAndroidProject ****
bash -c ndk-build 
Install        : libhello-jni.so => libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so
/cygdrive/c/make-3.82/install: line 1: Installation: command not found
/cygdrive/c/make-3.82/install: line 2: AndroidManifest.xml: command not found
/cygdrive/c/make-3.82/install: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `C'
/cygdrive/c/make-3.82/install: line 4: `Copyright (C) 1994, 1995, 1996, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2004 Free'
make: *** [libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so] Error 2
/cygdrive/c/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:418: recipe for target `libs/armeabi/libhello-jni.so' failed

12:23:45 Build Finished (took 1s.82ms)
```

I'm pretty sure I included all the necessary files and directories and set up the PATH environment variable(in Windows) correctly, but I have no idea why it keeps giving me this error.

edit: Forgot to mention that I was able to compile the code successfully in the Cygwin (latest version) shell.  I just want to know if there is a way to do this with Eclipse (Juno), ADT v20.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should follow [the ADT instructions](http://tools.android.com/recent/usingthendkplugin).

Generally speaking, NDK r8b comes with its prebuilt version of **make**, and can be used without **cygwin** altogether. For this case, it has  **ndk-build.cmd**.

Comment: I was able to get this up and running with those instructions.  Unfortunately, the native debugger did not work very well with one of samples I tried from the ndk folder, but I'll save that for another SO question.